# SSH allow arbitrary login with specified command

Tags: ssh

One of our Git servers recently went down and we have no way to get it back up soon, so we've redirected the DNS to a dummy (placeholder) host, which when accessed via HTTP / HTTPS, sends users to our notice board with 302. I want to configure this server so any user with or without an SSH key can log in to the `git` user, with commands limited to a preset one that writes a message (e.g. `command="echo 'a message here'",restrict`).

**I haven't figured out how to allow arbitrary login.** (Restricting commands is easy) Any ideas? (OpenSSH 7.9p1, Debian Buster)

Comment: You might be able to hack something together with a disproportionate amount of PAM, but the likelihood of either blowing everything up or leaving your system with a goatse-sized security hole are... significant.

Answer (score 0):

There is the option `ForceCommand`:

> **ForceCommand**
>   Forces the execution of the command specified by ForceCommand, ignoring any command supplied by the client and ~/.ssh/rc if present.  The command is invoked by using the user's login shell with the -c option.  This applies to shell, command, or subsystem execution.  It is most useful inside a Match block.  The command originally supplied by the client is available in the SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND environment variable.  Specifying a command of internal-sftp will force the use of an in-process SFTP server that requires no support files when used with ChrootDirectory.  The default is none.

There seems to be no single option matching `restrict`, but there are individual options to disable the features mentioned:

> **restrict**
>   Enable all restrictions, i.e. disable port, agent and X11 forwarding, as well as disabling PTY allocation and execution of ~/.ssh/rc.

It may be easier to create a file to use as the shell for the `git` user:

```
#/bin/sh
echo 'a message here'
exit 1
```

As every command to be executed is passed to the user`s shell this limits the commands available to the client. It is possible to interpret the intended command by the client, but not necessary for your requirements.

Comment: Any idea how can I allow an arbitrary user to login? I know how to use `ForceCommand` in a `Match User git` block.